# Create a Git Alias specific to one project

Tags: bash, git-bash, git-alias

I have a Python project that is compiled using `pyinstaller`. It usually uses a bunch of concatenated operations `&&` to not only compile, but perform several other things. Ok, just a big command.

I can use an alias with git bash to reduce it to a single word, fine. But I want to know, if exists some way to distribute some bash file with that alias with my project.

I mean, in my repo, having something like `alias.sh` that contains the alias I want, but they just exists inside that repo, so whenever I open a terminal inside that repo, I already have present those alias. And if someone forks or clones my project, they already have that alias too thanks to that specific file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

But you can create a script file `alias.sh` to set up the alias and instruct users of your repo via README file to source this file once in their terminal session when they need this alias: `. ./alias.sh`

The file `alias.sh` might contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
alias youralias='your | long | command'
```

After the file was sourced with `. ./alias.sh`, you can simply run `youralias` as a standalone command.

Comment: Can you edit to provide an example on how to set-up that alias.sh? I don't know about bash